# Hertzian dipole in time varying electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, induction, antennas

Suppose we place a Hertzian dipole (short, ends loaded with capacitance) in  a time varying electric field $\vec{E}\left(t\right)$, with magniture $E\left(t\right)$ and direction as shown in this figure. What will be the (steady state) current $I\left(t\right)$ flowing through the resistance $R$?

[image: Dipole in time-varying electric field]

I expect that if $E\left(t\right)$ is time invariant, there should be *no* current? So I was wondering if $\displaystyle \frac {d E\left(t\right)}{d t}$ appears in the expression somewhere?

I understand that the condition of a loop inside a time varying magnetic field is handled by Faraday's law, with the EMF given by $\displaystyle\mathscr{E}\left(t\right) = -\iint_A \frac{d\vec{B}\left(t\right)}{dt} \cdot d\vec{a}$. So is there something similar for the electric case?